# $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ $\rightarrow$ $SU(2) \rtimes U(1)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I normalize $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ do I get $SU(2) \rtimes U(1)$?
My thinking was that $SL(2,C)$ is isomorphic to $SU^{\mathbb{C}}(2)$ and when we normalize the field of complex numbers we get $U(1)$.

And apologies for brevity, that's about as much tex as I'll do on my phone.

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan by normalize I mean divide all elements of $\mathbb{C}$ by their absolute value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret the question to be asking about the image of the map $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{a}{|a|} & \frac{b}{|b|} \\ \frac{c}{|c|} & \frac{d}{|d|} \end{array} \right]$ where the domain is $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. This map is *not* a group homomorphism so this isn't a particularly natural question, and the result generally will not land in $SU(2)$ or $U(2)$. For example, the matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1+i & 1 \\ 2i-1 & 1+i \end{array} \right]$ is in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ but its componentwise normalization is $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} & 1 \\ \frac{2i-1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array} \right]$ which has determinant $- i - \frac{2i-1}{\sqrt{5}}$, so it is not even in $U(2)$.

More abstractly, a matrix in $U(2)$ is supposed to have orthonormal columns but this procedure produces a matrix whose columns consist of complex numbers of norm $1$, so the norm of a column will almost always be larger than $1$ unless it has only one nonzero entry.

I interpret the *motivation* of your question to be about how to generalize the polar decomposition $z = re^{i \theta}$ of a complex number to matrices. This has a very satisfying answer: matrices in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ have a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) $M = PU$ into a product of a positive-definite matrix $P$ and a unitary matrix $U$. The positive-definite matrix $P$ plays the role of the "absolute value" here and is given by $\sqrt{M^{\dagger} M}$ exactly as in the $1$-dimensional case. This gives us a "normalization" map

$$GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \ni M \mapsto \sqrt{M^{\dagger} M}^{-1} M \in U(n)$$

which is also not a group homomorphism but is still a useful map to know about since it can be promoted to a [deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract), showing that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is [homotopy equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) to $U(n)$ (and similarly that $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is homotopy equivalent to $SU(n)$); this comes up in algebraic topology.

Comment: Thank you, you're interpretations of my motivation were spot on!